# Git : Moving commit diverges branches

Tags: github

I have a repo with a master branch of 4 commits, then I created a new branch (b2) and made the fifth commit.

after I merged b2 to master. `$ git merge b2` and I got :

[image]

Now I wanna change the order of commit 2 so I made ($ git rebase -i HEAD~5).

Then I got this result :

[image]

and the result I want is :
1-3-4-2-5(HEAD → master, b2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rebase, the commits that you reorder change. That is because inside the commit there is a reference to the parent commit. If you reorder them, the parent commits change, so the references change and as a result, the commit themselves change. You can see this in your log, because the hashes (the 7-character codes in blue) changes for commit 4.

All downstream commits change as well, because their parent is now different. As a result, all commits downstream (more recent) change.

Your branch b2 points to a specific commit, namely 87c3249. When you rebase master, master points to a new commit (7812364), but that doesn't change b2.

If you want to fix this, run `git branch -f b2` when master is checked out. It creates a new branch at the same position as master with the name b2, and forces it (-f), meaning you remove the existing branch first.

This is only a viable option if b2 and master point to the same commit. If b2 is ahead of master, you should probably create a new branch at master (let's say b3), and then cherry-pick the commits from the b2 branch that are ahead of master.

```
git checkout master
git tag old-master  # tag for later reference
git rebase -i  # rebase master
git branch b3  # create new branch at the same commit as master
git checkout b3
git cherry-pick old-master...b2  # cherry-pick the commits between the old master and b2
```

Now b3 should be ahead of master with the same commits b2 used to be ahead of master. You can now remove b2 and rename b3 to b2.